# React App Disappears After Running It Via Express

Tags: reactjs, express

My React App runs perfectly fine when I run index.js. However, now I'm trying to move it to an Express server and when I refresh the page, I see the app run for about .5 seconds before it disappears to a white screen. I've taken out code, moved it all around, and I don't know how to fix this issue.

I added another div in index.html (just saying "hello") and that stays, while my div "root" disappears.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is server.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

// create a new instance of Express application
const app = express();

// add middleware to parse incoming requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// define the API routes for your application
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'API initialized' });
});

// other routes will be defined here
//app.use('/api/items', items);
app.use('/api', router);

// connect to MongoDB database using Mongoose
const conn_str = 'mongodb+srv://ashley:<password>@cluster0.vifnths.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

console.log(__dirname);

// serve static assets in production
app.use(express.static('build'));

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect(conn_str, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
})
.then(() => {
    app.listen(port)
    console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded...')
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error in DB Connection ${err}');
});
```

I've taken out code and moved it all around. I can't seem to fix the problem, despite knowing what it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this bit of code:

```js
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

It serves `index.html` as a response to all requests. However, you do not only need to serve `index.html`, but other assets as well (such as the JavaScript bundle, which contains your actual React app code).

So, try removing that route, because this middleware already covers this functionality:

```js
app.use(express.static('build'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out the answer! I was missing these two lines:

```
const items = require('./routes/api/items');

app.use('/api/items', items);
```

Basically I was calling `items` later in my code and I guess it was just not loading because I had no `items` to call from.